# How to complete NaN cells based on another Pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following 2 dataframes..

First dataframe **df1**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1 = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col1': [13, np.nan, 15, np.nan], 'col2': [23, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df1

    id  col1    col2
0   1   13.0    23.0
1   2   NaN     NaN
2   3   15.0    NaN
3   4   NaN     NaN
```

And the second dataframe **df2**:

```
d2 = {'id': [2, 3, 4], 'col1': [ 14, 150, 16], 'col2': [24, 250, np.nan]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df2

    id  col1    col2
0   2   14      24.0
1   3   150     250.0
2   4   16      NaN
```

I need to replace the **NaN** fields in **df1** with the **non-NaN** values from **df2**, where it is possible. But there are some conditions...

**Condition 1)** **id** column in each dataframe consists of unique values. When replacing any NaN value in **df1** with another value from **df2**, the **id** column value needs to match.

**Condition 2)** Dataframes do not necessarily have the same size.

**Condition 3)** NaN values will only be looked for in **col1** or **col2** in any of the dataframes. The **id** column cannot be NaN in any row. There might be other columns in the dataframes, with or without NaN values. But for replacing the data, we will only be looking at **col1** and **col2** columns.

**Condition 4)** To go for a replacement of a row in **df1**, it is enough that any of **col1** or **col2** have a NaN value in any corresponding row. And when any NaN value is detected in any row in **df1**, the entire row will be replaced by the corresponding row with the same **id** value from **df2**, **as long as all values of **col1** and **col2** in the corresponding row of df2 are non-NaN**. With other words, if the row with the same id value in **df2** have NaN value in any of **col1** or **col2**, do not replace any data in **df1**.

After doing this operation, the **df1** should look like the following:

```
    id  col1    col2
0   1   13.0    23.0
1   2   14      24    
2   3   150.0   250.0    # Note that the entire row is replaced!
3   4   NaN     NaN      # This row not replaced bcz col2 value is NaN in df2 for the same row
```

How can this be done in the most elegant way? Python offers a lot of functions that I may not be aware of, which maybe solves this problem in a few rows instead of writing a very complex logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the `NaN` values from `df2`, then update with `concat` and `groupby`:

```
pd.concat([df2.dropna(), df1]).groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
   id   col1   col2
0   1   13.0   23.0
1   2   14.0   24.0
2   3  150.0  250.0
3   4    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution is replacing the corresponding row in df1 even when the row does not have NaN values; but I can live with it. However, dropna() removes all rows if any NaN value is detected; how can I update it so that df2.dropna() only considers col1 and col2 bcz there my be other columns in the dataframe with or without NaN values but such columns are not supposed to be considered?

Comment: `dropna(subset=['col1','col2'])`?

Comment: Thakn you for your prompt answer!

Answer (score 1):

here is another way using `fillna`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('id').fillna(df2.dropna().set_index('id')).reset_index()
```

output:

```
>>>
   id  col1   col2
0   1  13.0   23.0
1   2  14.0   24.0
2   3  15.0  250.0
3   4   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: This works as well. I just need to update the dropna() as dropna(subset=['col1','col2']) as Quang Hoang suggested in his answer. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!